# I am new in Vue.js try to understand vue-socket.io but failed

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-5

I am new in Vue.js try to understand vue-socket.io but failed

i used this to install https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io and code

import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://xxxxx.local:1923');
in my App.js , i am try to make a transaction socket when ever transaction made its reflect in web socket . i need a example of all files which i have to code or you can say that file structure which file i need and where to place all files.

like import file is done in main.js
test connection is done in Components.vue file 
but where to handle my php code (Laravel 5.5) and js server file

please guide me with example links if you have

Answer (score 0):

I used [this tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/) to help my with Vue.js. It does not use the `Vue-Socket` but `pusher` instead. But the behavior remain the same.

You will see what you need.

Basicaly you have to follow the folowing steps

- Setup a broadcast system in `config/broadcasting.php`
- Define your model & controller
- Add routes (`routes/web.php`)
- Create your `Vue`s and `components`
- Setup the `boradcast` and `listening` events

Comment: Thanks , But i need to do with Socket I.O , Pusher have limited one day send and received data, if we want unlimited than we need Socket I.O